# new mysqli class error when connecting to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am currently trying to connect a web application to my mysql database but I just keep getting a 'Class mysqli' not found error.

Here's the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sparkbusiness_jamie";
$password = "Firefrazzy01";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you written this within another class? Or just in a simple page?

Comment: `Sounds like you just need to install MySQLi.`

Comment: Have you installed and enabled the mysqli library on your server?

Comment: you can use the follwing command line instruction to find out  if it is installed:
`php -m | grep -i mysql`